# /bin/sh: 1: node_modules/.bin/nodemon: not found

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, npm-install

I have some issues with `nodemon` installation. I installed:

```
RUN npm install --save express
RUN npm install nodemon -g --save
```

When i launch my application i get:

```
node_modules/.bin/nodemon app/server.js
/bin/sh: 1: node_modules/.bin/nodemon: not found
```

I went over some similar questions, And nothing helped so far.

Please advise.

Comment: It is not clear if you get an error **when you try to install nodemon** or, in the other hand, if you get this error when trying to launch your application with: `$ node_modules/.bin/nodemon app/server.js`.

Comment: I get this error when i launch my application.

Comment: which OS you are using? Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When you install an npm module with the `-g` flag, it gets installed **globally**. This means it won't get installed in the `node_modules` of the project. However, it should be available globally, as a command-line program, so:

`$ nodemon app/server.js`

should just work.